# if array is in_array() in array?

Tags: php, arrays

First time trying to find something in an array using an array as both a needle and a haystack. So, example of 2 arrays:

My Dynamically formed array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 
    [1] => zpp 
    [2] => enroll 
)
```

My Static comparison array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => enroll 
)
```

And my `in_array()` if statement:

```
if (in_array($location_split, $this->_acceptable)) {
   echo 'found';
}
$location_split; // is my dynamic
$this->_acceptable // is my static
```

But from this found is not printed out, as I'd expect it to be? What exactly am I failing on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i'm understanding you right, you want to see whether the first array's entries are present in the second array.

You might look at `array_intersect`, which would return you an array of stuff that's present in all the arrays you pass it.

```
$common = array_intersect($this->_acceptable, $location_split);
if (count($common)) {
    echo 'found';
}
```

If the count of that array is at least 1, then there's at least one element in common.  If it's equal to your dynamic array's length, and the array's values are distinct, then they're all in there.

And, of course, the array will be able to tell you *which* values matched.

Comment: I want to see if any of the static array values exist in the dynamic one. But not all or nothing if that makes sense.

Comment: @chris: Then check whether the count from the array returned by `array_intersect` is at least 1.  Added a code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Because there is no element in your array containing `array('enroll')` in it (only `'enroll'`).

Your best bet would be to use `array_diff()`, if the result is the same as the original array, no match is found.

Answer (score 0):

You are interchanging the parameters for `in_array` (needle & haystack). It needs to be,

```
 if(in_array($this->_acceptable, $location_split))
{
  echo 'found';
 }
```

**Edit:** Try using `array_intersect`.

[Demo](http://codepad.org/uB8en8b3)

Comment: tried it that way to, thats what I first thought myself, but its the same either direction